# Find out when recaptcha has loaded

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Is there a way to find out when recaptcha has loaded so I can run some javascript code? I want to do that because depending on my Internet connection sometimes HTML elements will load before recaptcha loads. I want to load everything together.

**EDIT**

I'm interested to find out when Recaptcha.create() loads, not when the external JS file loads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476105/is-there-a-way-to-detect-whether-an-external-javascript-file-is-fully-loaded